# Good practice to pass functions like this?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have following scenario, where I subscribe in Component A to a Subject (`service.save`) and I want to call some functions of Component B,C,D,E before this event is going through. I thought of something like this:

```
//Component A only one subscribing
this.service.save.subscribe((event)=>{
    this.sharedService.beforeSaveFunctions.forEach(fn => {
        fn(event);
    });
    // ... do something
});


@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  beforeSaveFunctions: any[];

  registerBeforeSaveFunction(fn:any){
      this.beforeSaveFunctions.push(fn);
  }
}


//Component B, C, D, ...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.registerBeforeSaveFunction(handleSave.bind(this));
}

handleSave(event){
    //Do something..
}
```

So every component can call `this.sharedService.registerBeforeSaveFunction()` to pass their own function, which gets later executed on the subscription in Component A.

Is this good style? I have no access to the service which holds the `save` Subject, since it is an external library. If I subscribe to it in every component, and every component does it's own thing it gets messy and I have async problems with one subscription finishing before the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe wrap the external library service inside the "SharedService", and expose the "save" Observable as a member of the SharedService like this:

```
// Component A only one subscribing
this.sharedService.save.subscribe((event) => {
    // ... do something
});

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    save = this.service.save
        .pipe(
            tap(event => this.beforeSaveFunctions.forEach(fn => fn(event)))
        );

    constructor(private service: Service) { }

    beforeSaveFunctions: any[];

    registerBeforeSaveFunction(fn: any) {
        this.beforeSaveFunctions.push(fn);
    }
}

//Component B, C, D, ...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.registerBeforeSaveFunction(handleSave.bind(this));
}

handleSave(event){
    //Do something..
}
```